# How to force Python 2 to raise exception when comparing different types?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Comparing a string with an int in Python 2.7.2 looks very inconsistent:

```
x = '12'; y = 3
print x > y      # True
x = 12; y = '3'
print x > y      # False
```

According to 
[How does Python compare string and int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270680/how-does-python-compare-string-and-int)
in Python 3 these will raise an exception. Is there a way to get Python 2 already behave that way? Looking at the[`__future__`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/__future__.html)I could not figure out if there is such a feature.

Comment: hey hope you can find your solution in this question :- 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270680/how-does-python-compare-string-and-int

Comment: @AnuragSharma: Given that he had that same link in his question, and summarized its answer, I doubt that will help him much.

Answer (score 4):

No. Your choices are:

- Write and use wrapper classes that raise on unwanted comparisons.
- Write and use custom comparison functions in place of the usual operators.
- Use something like MacroPy to make your custom comparison functions less odious to use.
- Don't rely on these semantics.
- Pre-check values before comparing.
- Use Python 3 when you want Python 3.

Comment: "Use Python 3 when you want Python 3." +1

Answer (score 2):

You can't monkeypatch builtin types (at least not without going to the C source), nor should you. You can only subclass them and have them raise `TypeError` on illegal comparisons.

This is the correct, if problematic, behavior for Python 2, so the best thing you could do is switch to Python 3 which is more sensible in this and many other regards.